# AJAX request not routing to the right url

Tags: ajax, url

I'm having trouble with an ajax call. I don't end up on the right page.

```
<script>
    function showsql(form)
    {
        var str=form.q.value;
        if (str=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML="1";

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML="2";
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadstatechange = function()
        {
            if(xml.http.readState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML=xml.responseText;
            }
            document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML="4";
        }
        var url="index.php";
        url = url+"?at=stats";
        url = url+"&q="+str;
        document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML=url;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        //document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML="3";

    }
</script>

<form action="" method="GET" >
SELECT <input  type="text" name="q" id="q" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" action="showsql(this.form) "/>
</form>
<div id="sqlreturn">
</div>
```

With this I should be getting to index.php?at=stats&q=. I end up on index.php?q= instead. Any idea why this is or how to fix it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.onreadstatechange
```

should be

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

Is this your working code? It has many other errors similar to above. See

```
if(xml.http.readState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
      document.getElementById("sqlreturn").innerHTML=xml.responseText;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Problem is even though you are sending ajax request first, just after that, form do submit as normal http GET request. Because you have used a submit button **(input type="submit")** instead of normal button **(input type="button")** and you haven't prevent the default submit event.

Therefore replace the submit button using a normal button. For that just replace *type* attribute with value "**button**". And I don't think there is a attribute called action for input element. You should use **onclick** attribute instead of action for input element.

Comment: Oops, didn't catch that. It didn't fix my big problem, but would have probably caused a headache later. I'm not sure what you mean by working code. The code itself doesn't work, but it is what I am trying to get to work. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried changing it to onclick, however when I do that, nothing happens. The javascript function showsql runs. It creates the url properly, but after that it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Kamis use Firebug firefox extension (its net panel) to debug ajax request and response. Have you corrected the errors I pointed out before in xmlhttp related code? Anyway If you are referring to why you always get "4" in the div instead of response, because you replace html of the div "sqlreturn" again after that if condition by "4".